# Swift: starting and stopping the animation of an activity indicator inside a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to put an activity indicator inside a custom class so I can start/stop it from any view controller.

The below code works when starting the activity indicator but not stopping, how can I do this?

```
static func activityIndicatorFunction(view: UIView, targetVC: UIViewController, animate: Bool) {

    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    if animate == false {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    } else {
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.17, blue:0.21, alpha:1)
        activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        activityIndicator.center = targetVC.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        //UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
}
```

**An example of starting the activity indicator**, the animate parameter would be false if I wanted to stop it.

```
Utils.activityIndicatorFunction(view: view, targetVC: self, animate: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it best just to set a 'tag' to the activity indicator and then reference to that when stopping the animation, using one function to hide and one to show as Ahmad suggested. Ahmad F's answer and Guillermo's answer seem good as well.

**Show/hide functions inside my Utils.swift file:**

```
static func showActivityIndicator(view: UIView, targetVC: UIViewController) {

    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.17, blue:0.21, alpha:1)
    activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    activityIndicator.center = targetVC.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    activityIndicator.tag = 1
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}

static func hideActivityIndicator(view: UIView) {
    let activityIndicator = view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIActivityIndicatorView
    activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
    activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}
```

**Calling show function:**

```
Utils.showActivityIndicator(view: view, targetVC: self)
```

**Calling hide function:**

```
Utils.hideActivityIndicator(view: view)
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfect candidate for protocol extensions. I recently did this myself.

#### First create the protocol in a file, say ActivityIndicatorPresenter.swift

```
/// Used for ViewControllers that need to present an activity indicator when loading data.
public protocol ActivityIndicatorPresenter {
    
    /// The activity indicator
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView { get }
    
    /// Show the activity indicator in the view
    func showActivityIndicator()
    
    /// Hide the activity indicator in the view
    func hideActivityIndicator()
}
```

#### Create a protocol extension (in the same file...or a different one)

```
public extension ActivityIndicatorPresenter where Self: UIViewController {
    
    func showActivityIndicator() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
            self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80) //or whatever size you would like
            self.activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: self.view.bounds.height / 2)
            self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }
    }
    
    func hideActivityIndicator() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Any view controller can then conform to the protocol

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ActivityIndicatorPresenter {

/// Make sure to add the activity indicator
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

//Suppose you want to load some data from the network in this view controller
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showActivityIndicator() //Wow you can use this here!!!
    getSomeData { data in 
        //do stuff with data
        self.hideActivityIndicator()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest is to implement them as two separated methods, also to add them into extension of `UIViewController`, as follows:

**UIViewController extension:**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showActivityIndicator() {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.17, blue:0.21, alpha:1)
        activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        //UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        activityIndicator.tag = 100 // 100 for example

        // before adding it, you need to check if it is already has been added:
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if subview.tag == 100 {
                print("already added")
                return
            }
        }

        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }

    func hideActivityIndicator() {
        let activityIndicator = view.viewWithTag(100) as? UIActivityIndicatorView
        activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()

        // I think you forgot to remove it?
        activityIndicator?.removeFromSuperview()

        //UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
}
```

*I assume that you want to always show/hide the `activityIndicator` it to `ViewController.view`, if it is not, you might need let it an activityIndicator of `UIView` instead of `UIViewController`.*

**Usage:**

For example, consider that you have two IBActions, the first shows the activity indicator and the other one hides it, they should be like:

```
@IBAction func show(sender: AnyObject) {
    showActivityIndicator()
}

@IBAction func hide(sender: AnyObject) {
    hideActivityIndicator()
}
```

Comment: How to show or hide indicator using ternary operator? Like x = condition ? true : false, but with startAnimating() and stopAnimating()

Comment: @DaniSpringer for this case, you could combine the two methods in one, which takes a `Bool` parameter to display/hide the indicator, thus `combinedMethod(myCondition ? true : false)`.

Comment: Ah I see. I was playing with it before your reply and ended up doing something similar: I assign to a _ variable (not sure if there is a name for that) the result of a ternary check on whether to call one or the other. But that’s clean! Thanks